# Master Excel Spreadsheet Save Other Microsoft Docs

Tags: c#, excel, ms-office

I am wondering if it is possible to have a master Excel spreadsheet save-as other Microsoft files? I know how to save-as the current workbook into specific folders. For example:

I am trying to save a version with the date of 3 spreadsheets, 2 Word docs and 2 MS Project files with the click of one button from a Master spreadsheet into specified locations. This is going to be done weekly or twice a week so I wanted to automate this.

Is this possible or no? I have thought of using Git (limited experience) but I don't know if I can version many docs at once and if it would even be that much easier than just doing File-SaveAs. Or, if using C# instead of VBA to make it "more robust" since I am more experienced with C#.

Holler with any advice or feedback.

Thanks

Comment: We don't put "solved" in titles.  Just accept the answer you posted by clicking on the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

So i figured it out.

I needed to be using the CopyFile and CopyFolder functions.

```
Sub CopyFolder(SourceFilePath As String, DestPath As String, OverWrite As Boolean)

  Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject

  Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
  Call FSO.CopyFolder(SourceFilePath, DestPath, OverWrite)

End Sub

Sub CopyFileAndRename(SourceFilePath As String, DestPath As String, OverWrite As Boolean)

  Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject

  Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
  Call FSO.CopyFile(SourceFilePath, DestPath, OverWrite)

End Sub
```

Then I just have a button with a Macro that calls the functions with the file locations and the new names.